# How to find the Main class file AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript

so i've decompiled a library.swf file, then i've got much AS3 files, and How can i know which of them is the Main?

Comment: In a library, there may not be a Main. Main is something you write exactly once per project, and so it is not something you would include into a reusable library.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the main as file, click your stage and type in the name in he properties panel